# Upgrades unlocked later in the game

Tags: 1000-amps

I have read [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/61029/3921) there are other upgrades besides teleportation. Could you list all the upgrades?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Teleport (click to zip to new location in room, does not teleport between rooms on the map)
- Increased Aura (radius of tile activation increases as energy in room increases)
- Sonar (hit down to show all tiles in unlit room)
- Shield (kill those effing enemies that turn nodes back off after you've turned them on)
- Awesome jump (seriously, rockets you up and out of rooms)
- Infinite battery